# Compare items of a list of list and choose the biggest

Tags: python

```
lista = [['Apertura','174830','Apertura - Home - Header_n','Variable (950x90)','AR','1','0','0.82','81','1.23',0.3,3],
         ['Apertura','174830','Apertura - Home - Header_n','Variable (950x90)','AR','1','0','0.82','81','1.23',0.25,5]
]
```

I need to compare all the items on my list.
Within each item, we use all items except the last two to compare.
if there are items that are the same we choose the item that has the lowest number of the last item that we do not take to compare

```
>>>['Apertura','174830','Apertura - Home - Header_n','Variable (950x90)','AR','1','0','0.82','81','1.23',0.3,3]
```

I used this form but know I can't do it with that.

```
lista = [min(g, key=itemgetter(-2)) for _, g in groupby(lista, key=lambda s: s[:-2])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  1 lista = [
  2     [
  3         'Apertura','174830','Apertura - Home - Header_n','Variable (950x90)',
  4         'AR','1','0','0.82','81','1.23',0.3,3
  5     ],   
  6     [
  7         'Apertura','174830','Apertura - Home - Header_n','Variable (950x90)',
  8         'AR','1','0','0.82','81','1.23',0.25,5
  9     ]
 10 ]
 11 
 12 if lista[0][:-2] == lista[1][:-2]:
 13     if lista[0][-1] < lista[1][-1]:
 14         print(lista[0])
 15     else:
 16         print(lista[1])
```

**Output**

```
['Apertura', '174830', 'Apertura - Home - Header_n', 'Variable (950x90)', 'AR', '1', '0', '0.82', '81', '1.23', 0.3, 3]
```

If I am understanding what you are seeking correctly, could we just do compare the list up to the second to last item, then if equal just compare the last item?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use sorted with `key` argument instead of `itertools.groupby`:

```
print(sorted(lista,key=lambda x: x[-2]))
```

OR:

```
lista.sort(key=lambda x: x[-2])
print(lista)
```